# Google sheets custom script pass relative string

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

What I want to do is

`=getColor(string(Y16),$A$1)`

where `getColor()` is a custom function and `Y16` is a cell in my spreadsheet

The function works if I do

`=getColor("Y16",$A$1)`

But the problem is if I add a row or column that moves `Y16` to `Z16` the parameter that I'm passing into `getColor()` is still `"Y16"` as it's hard coded in. I want the equation to change to

`=getColor(string(Z16),$A$1)'

if a row is ever added.

Anyone have any thoughts on this? I haven't had much luck on the google machine....

Answer (score 0):

`=getColor(Address(row(Z16),column(Z16),4),$A$1)`